pywinauto: how to get rid of delays in clicks
import time
from pywinauto.application import Application
import os

#Installer path
pycharm_exe = r"G:\Softwarewa\JetBrains PyCharm\JetBrains PyCharm Professional 2023.1 [FileCR]\JetBrains PyCharm Professional 2023.1\pycharm-professional-2023.1.exe"

app = Application(backend="uia").start(pycharm_exe)

# Wait for window to appear
while True:
    if app.PyCharmSetup.exists() == True:
        break

#activate the window
app.PyCharmSetup.window()

# app.PyCharmSetup.print_control_identifiers()
app.PyCharmSetup.Next.click()

#click on next again
app.PyCharmSetup.Next.click()

#click on next once again
#app.PyCharmSetup.print_control_identifiers()

hi there, i am trying to automate PyCharm installation but there is a problem with script when it reaches where it starts to click on "Next" button it takes about 3 sec to click next button again.... how do i get rid of these delays between clicks?

Thart's a question that I had myself. Maybe you have to study the repo itself and work with ctypes to find a solution to the delays that come with pyautogui https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/blob/master/pyautogui/_pyautogui_win.py

You need to modify global timings. See the bottom of this guide:
https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wait_long_operations.html#global-timings-for-all-actions
But please be careful, especially about setting all timings to zero. It may affect reliability of the automation steps. Because often some time is needed to handle some events at the app side. Maybe Timings.fast() is better in general.
